# Why public method cannot access private member when defined within the class scope

Tags: javascript, prototype

In some javascript video tutorial ([Private members in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpxfKy_Dvo4)) there is an explanation of what are private, privileged and public members and this piece of code example is shown :

```
function Emloyee(firstName, lastName){

    // Private field
    var privateFullName;

    // Public fields
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;   

    // Private function 
    var privateGetFullName = function(){
        privateFullName = firstName + " " + lastName; 
        return privateFullName;
    }

    // Privileged function
    this.privilegedGetFullName = function(){
        return privateGetFullName();
    } 

    // Public function
    Employee.prototype.publicGetFullName = function(){
        return this.privilegedGetFullName ();
    }
}
```

and it was said that public methods can call privileged methods but not private method. I would agree with this if the public function defined as an inner function in this example would be defined outside this class example but in the case of this example it's defined within the class scope where private members exist so why that public function doesn't take the private member value as does a closure ?

Also i would mention that before watching this tutorial what are called privileged and public methods in this example for me they were both same and were just public (i didn't know that the first should be called privileged) and that we call the one extending the class prototype as public function, i just used to know that we should use the prototype when we have to add a method with the this keyword to an already defined class.

Comment: *"so why that public function doesn't take the private member value as does a closure ?"* – Not quite sure what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: I simply wanted to ask why that public function extending the prototype cannot access the private member ? (as an inner function which become a closure when it keeps a variable value inside of itself )

Comment: It is possible to access private variables in public function in javaScript. Only difference between previliged and public function that I see is that each instantiation will result in memory being used for previliged function but in case of public function all instantiations will be reusing the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public method `Employee.prototype.publicGetFullName` has to be defined outside `Employee` constructor function.

When you use it inside and refer to a private function, then it will be redefined on each instantiation and so it will return the 'private' data of the last created instance instead of this instance.